# Переход на другую активность в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, activity, android-on-click

Как реализовать переход на другую активность по нажатию на пункт `recyclerview`?
Я добавил в класс адаптера:

```
    class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Recept recept;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    void setRecord(Recept recept) {
        this.recept = recept;
    }
}
```

Но подобная конструкция не позволяет мне создать намерения для перехода. Как реализовать переход?

Comment: Почему не позволяет? Нет контекста?

Comment: @YungBlade, Я ведь не могу использовать такой код `Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,LastActivity.class); ` В своем классе адаптера

Comment: В onClick попробуйте Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),LastActivity.class);

Comment: @YungBlade Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можнo попробовать так:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
private Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Короче говоря, я так понял, вы не знаете, где взять экземпляр контекста для конструктора интента. Это можно сделать так:

1. Передать экземпляр контекста в конструкторе класса адаптера, как предложил Shevchyk Vitalii.
2. Получить контекст из view, как написал я.

Имейте ввиду, что не рекомендуется хранить экземпляр контекста в переменной, потому что это чревато утечками памяти, лучше получать его откуда-то.